# Collect data from POST route by fetch

Tags: node.js, fetch

Hi I'm trying to implement some little exercise using Nodejs.

Have index.ejs page with input and submit buttom:

index.ejs:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="button-addon1">Button</button>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="userInput" class="form-control" name="input" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="output">test</div>
</div>
```

How do I make it work proper and change my output innerHTML to created n text?

After the user fill the input tag and press the button my /public/javascripts/index.js file using fetch and sends users input to POST request root "/".

/public/javascripts/index.js:

```
document.getElementById('button-addon1').addEventListener('click', () => {

    var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ input }),
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    }

    fetch('/', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(({n}) => {

            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = n})
});
```

My POST root  receives the user input from the fetch and adds "addon" string to user input and return back to my index.js file.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { input: '' });
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => { 
  var n = req.body;
  n = n.input + "addon";
  res.status(200).json({n})
})
```

The index.js file should change my div id="output" to the n from POST route.

But the problem is that whenever I push the button my browser returns json file like this:

[image: browser returns after button pressing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want a form to trigger javascript instead of triggering the browser to do an HTTP call, you have to use `e.preventDefault()`:

```js
document.getElementById('button-addon1').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ input }),
        headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    }

    fetch('/', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(({n}) => {

            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = n})
});
```